# Integral of Taylor for a Generic Function

Tags: calculus, integration, taylor-expansion

I can't seem to figure out the solution to this problem:

### Problem:

Find a series for the following equation and give the first 3 terms and the $nth$ term:$$g(x) = \int_3^xf(t) \; dt$$

The problem also asks for the general term in summation form. Do I just assume that a = 0 and take the Maclaurin here?

Comment: Generally the easiest way to represent functions (that are hard to integrate as they are) is as Taylor Approximation around 0 unless otherwise specified.

Comment: In this case I would find a Taylor Approx at $x = 3$ because we at least know that $g$ is defined there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a Taylor Series approximation centered at x=3.

As Alex Mercado said in the comments, it is valid to center the Taylor Series around x=3 because f(t) must be defined there.

The Taylor series of g(x) centered at x = 3 is

$\left(\frac{1}{0!}\right)g(3)(x-3)^0 + \left(\frac{1}{1!}\right)g'(3)(x-3)^1 + \left(\frac{1}{2!}\right)g''(3)(x-3)^2....$

We know that g is defined by an integral, and integrating from 3 to 3(=x) means that g(3) = 0.

Therefore, we can write this series in terms of f, since, after all, f is the derivative of g.

So this series is just $f(3)(x-3) + \frac{1}{2}f'(3)(x-3)^2 + \frac{1}{6}f''(3)(x-3)^3...$

The nth term of this series is $\frac{1}{n!}f^{n-1}(3)(x-3)^n$, where $f^n(x)$ is the nth derivative of f, or the nth+1 derivative of g.